# Retrieving multiple check boxes from a form with a "foreach"

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox, foreach

Here is the form with checkboxes. I need to print out the text, but not the value of the checkboxes.

```
  <p>Select the cinema where you saw the film<br />
    Richmond <input type="checkbox" name="cinema" value="Wimbledon" /><br />
    Kingston <input type="checkbox" name="cinema" value="Sutton" /><br />
    Feltham <input type="checkbox" name="cinema" value="Kingston" /><br />
    </p>
```

Here is the response page with foreach loop given by our teacher, which seems like it doesn't work

```
>  <?php
>     $cinema =$_POST['cinema'];
>     
>     foreach ( $cinema as $cinemalocation) {
>              print "Cinema Location:".$cinemalocation."<br />";
>            };
>     ?>
```

I am also not allowed to make adjustments to the form, Ive been trying to find the answer for hours. Nothing seems to be helpful so far.

Comment: Unless you have an array or db or something to lookup the relation from value to text, you would need to modify the form to get the text.

Comment: I agree. The surrounding html is not being passed to the form handler and therefore not available.

Comment: But if it is a school assignment (teacher mentioned) with this limited scenario, you could build a simple if-else structure to fulfill the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible given that you can't modify the form. GETting and POSTing a form just sends what you have in the value attribute.

If you were able to change the form, you could set an ID on the elements and use javascript.

Also, given that your inputs are self closed

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cinema" value="Wimbledon" />
```

There isn't actually anything in their HTML field.

UPDATE:
Given that you mentioned your instructor wants an if elseif solution, perhaps this is what you're looking for`

```
<?php
 $cinema =$_POST['cinema'];

 foreach ( $cinema as $cinemalocation) {
            //  print "Cinema Location:".$cinemalocation."<br />";
    if( $cinemalocation == 'Wimbledon'){
echo "Cinema Location: Richmond <br />";
}
elseif  if( $cinemalocation == 'Sutton'){
    echo "Cinema Location: Kingston <br />";
}

elseif  if( $cinemalocation == 'Kingston'){
    echo "Cinema Location: Feltham  <br />";
}

else{
echo "Cinema Location: Unknown  <br />";
}
       };
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can alter the given response page code, and also assuming this is a limited scenario where needed values are just known, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
    $cinema = $_POST['cinema'];
    foreach ( $cinema as $cinemalocation) {
        if ($cinemalocation == 'Wimbledon') {
            print "Cinema Location: Richmond<br/>";
        } elseif ($cinemalocation == 'Sutton') {
            print "Cinema Location: Kingston<br/>";
        } elseif ($cinemalocation == 'Kingston') {
            print "Cinema Location: Feltham<br/>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Once again, this is based off the limited instructions and information provided. As others have pointed out, this is not best practice or even real world scenario based. The html isn't passed back in the POST, and even if it was, there are much better ways to achieve output of values based on selections posted.